# Excel Filter Button

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to make this button clear or invisible? I want to use the filter button but I do not want to have to deal with having the gray arrow button taking up space and ruining the presentation of my tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

Go to Tools>Options>View and checkmark "hide all" under the Objects section.

Retrieved from http://www.excelforum.com/excel-new-users-basics/358807-filter-do-not-want-the-ugly-drop-down-button.html

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore. It hides the objects but the arrows are still there.

Comment: There is an option using advanced filters (as well as some other workarounds) explained in the link I posted...It's possible those may work for you...?